# How do I persistently set the MTU for a PPTP VPN connection in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I have a M$-based VPN connection that I connect to every so often. After connecting to the VPN server, I need to run `sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1200`, So that I can log on to the server, or else `ssh` client will respond with `expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP`.

I want to store this mtu setting persistently so I do not have to run that command everytime I connect to the VPN. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: If it is a PPP interface then there must be a `pppd` running? If so, pass `mtu 1200` on `pppd`'s command line? For example by including it in `/etc/ppp/options` or `/etc/ppp/your-peer-name`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom shell script at this address : /etc/network/if-up.d/set-pptp.sh,

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "ppp0" ]; then
   ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1200
fi
```

finally make executable like so:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/network/if-up.d/set-pptp.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from shgnInc is on the right track, but, at least on ubuntu, the script can't have a ".sh" extension (ref https://askubuntu.com/questions/406126/why-is-ifup-not-running-all-of-the-if-pre-up-d-scripts), and ubuntu seems to prefer ip rather than ipconfig, so the ifconfig line would become:

```
ip link set dev ppp0 mtu 1200
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. If your post is meant to improve an existing answer rather than suggesting a different kind of solution, please don't post it as a new answer. Rather, place a comment below the answer you want to improve, or submit an edit suggestion that would incorporate your improvements to that answer.